# How to let MSI reboot without user interaction before installation finished?

Tags: windows, windows-installer

I'm building the MSI using Visual Studio Installer Project. One requirement I have is automatically reboot system before installation finished. By saying 'automatically', I mean there is no customer interaction, e.g. click a button to trigger the reboot. Also, the reboot should to be suppressable by /norestart option to the msi.

I tried to edit MSI with Orca by adding the property REBOOT = Force. But this will pop a yes/no windows for user to click. Reboot will happen only after user click yes, which is not automatically.

Also I tried to call Win32 API **InitiateSystemShutdownEx** to initiate the reboot. But in this case, I can't disable the reboot by /norestart option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [REBOOTPROMPT property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371104(v=vs.85).aspx)

> If the REBOOTPROMPT property is set to Suppress (or just S) any reboot
>   performed by the Windows Installer happens automatically without
>   interaction from the user. Setting this property does not initiate a
>   reboot if one is not needed, it only suppresses the display of any
>   prompts for reboots to the user.

BTW, one of the many shortcomings of Visual Studio setup projects is they don't give you a place to author this.  You have to postbuild hack the MSI using ORCA or some script if using CI builds.  It's like using ILDASM to tweak a DLL because VB.NET didn't support something.   The more elegant solution is to use a tool with better Windows Installer XML support such as Windows Installer XML.

Comment: Adding REBOOTPROMPT doesn't solve my problem. The reboot happens after user click 'close' when installation finished. I need to run the MSI in remote machine, and internet connect will lost during the installation. So user won't be able to click the 'close' button.

Comment: Is that possible to detect whether or not '/norestart' option is provided inside MSI?

Comment: You're question didn't mention anything about installing on a remote machine or internet connections.  You should just copy the MSI to the remote machine and from an elevated command prompt perform a silent installation.  E.g.  msiexec /I foo.msi /qn REBOOT=F /l*v install.log

Comment: You are right. If I run the msi with command line, the reboot will be done. However, if I rdp to the machine and double click to run the msi, internet connection will be lost during installation. And I never get the chance to do the reboot.

Comment: So what's the problem?  Don't do that then.  There are tools out there such as SCCM to handle doing all of this in an automated fashion with rich reporting.

Comment: The problem is I want to support both UI and command line execution.